# absolute continuity of probability measure convolved with a mass measure

Tags: probability, convolution, dirac-delta

I found that  if $\mu$ is a probability measure with compact support then $\mu * \delta_a$  can not be absolutely continuous w.r.t Lebesgue measure. Here $\delta_a$ is the Dirac measure supported at {a} and $a$ is non-zero.

I can't figure out how it can be justified. Any hints?

Comment: You want to say that if the distribution of r.v. $X$ is absolutely continuous and $a$ is a constant, then distribution of  $X+a$ can not be  absolutely continuous?  The PDF of $X+a$ w.r.t. Lebesgue measure is $f_X(x-a)$.

Comment: $f_X$ with compact support ?

Comment: It does not matter.

Comment: @NCh Thank you for your answer. I don't see an answer to my question in your response. My question is: can $\mu* \delta_a$   be absolutely continuous w.r.t Lebesgue measure when $\mu$ is compactly supported probability measure?

Comment: It is absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure iff $\mu$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: @NCh Thank you very much for your explanation.